# how to draw a multiline chart using python pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
Dept,Date,Que
ece,2015-06-25,96
ece,2015-06-24,89
ece,2015-06-26,88
ece,2015-06-19,87
ece,2015-06-23,82
ece,2015-06-30,82
eee,2015-06-24,73
eee,2015-06-23,71
eee,2015-06-25,70
eee,2015-06-19,66
eee,2015-06-27,60
eee,2015-06-22,56
mech,2015-06-27,10
mech,2015-06-22,8
mech,2015-06-25,8
mech,2015-06-19,7
```

I need multiline chart with grid based on Dept column, i need each Dept in one line.
For Ex:ece the sparkline should be 96,89,88,87,82,82.... like wise i need for other Dept also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = df.pivot(index='Dept', columns='Date', values='Que')
print df
Date  2015-06-19  2015-06-22  2015-06-23  2015-06-24  2015-06-25  2015-06-26  \
Dept                                                                           
ece         87.0         NaN        82.0        89.0        96.0        88.0   
eee         66.0        56.0        71.0        73.0        70.0         NaN   
mech         7.0         8.0         NaN         NaN         8.0         NaN   

Date  2015-06-27  2015-06-30  
Dept                          
ece          NaN        82.0  
eee         60.0         NaN  
mech        10.0         NaN  

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

You can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot).

[image: graph]